# How often do ETF's change holdings?

Tags: etf, stock-analysis

I realize all ETF's are probably on different schedules depending on who's managing them. My question is: is there a way to learn the schedule for when they modify their holdings?

Let's take [Invesco's QQQ](https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/xnas/qqq/quote) for example. Is there a simple (ish) way to find out when they have modified their underlying holdings? Or is there at least a way to see how the holdings have changed historically?

**EDIT**

the most helpful thing I've found, and it may be my answer is:

> the adviser adjusts the securities from time to time to conform to periodic changes in the identity and/or relative weights of index securities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an ETF follows and index (a passive ETF), then they make changes when the index makes changes. Their philosophy is to match the index. The index maker may periodically review the companies to see who makes the cut. They also make changes when companies are bought, merged, spun off, or go out of business.

If the ETF is not following an index (actively managed) then they make changes when they feel it is justified to help them reach their goal of beating an index.

Comment: Or their goal of tracking a sector of the market. Or whatever principle that fund is organized under, which you should know before buying into the fund.